# how to use groupby with respect of a row?

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

I want to do groupby with respect of a row:

```
col1  col2    col3   col4    col5
'A'    'B'      'B'   'A'     'B'
2       4        3     2       1
0       1        2     4       0
1       1        1     1       1
```

I want to filter this dataframe if two columns have the same values in the first row and put the average of them.

For example the first and the forth columns have the same value 'A` in the first row and the average of those row is :

```
first row: (2+2)/2=2
second row: (0+4)/2=2
third row: (1+1)/2=1
```

the same for columns with value `B`. so the output is

```
col1   col2
'A'      'B'
2        7/3
2        3/3
1        3/3
```

Comment: The **first row** has 2 'B' values, but how do you average letters? The **second row** has 2 values of 2 and the average of those is 2 `(2+2)/2 = 2` not 1 .  In short I really don't understand what you are seeking e.g. for the **third row** which has 2 values of 0 why does the average calculation contain 4 in it?

Comment: Can you please specify which database. "sql" by itself is not sufficient to identify the language dialect needed for queries i.e. each db has differences in SQL syntax.

Comment: You could do it with Window function with `first`, `when` to groupby the letter row, however, having the letter row ("A", "B") as column name (ie: A_col1, A_col4...) or pivot this table to have the letter row as a single column is probably the better approach.   Having a string and integer mixed in in the same column is not practical.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I am getting average of numbers is the have the same values in the first row.

Comment: @Emma If I make the first row as columns's name, how I can do it?

Comment: Also, I was confused first, you may want to update the question to say `second row: (2+2)/2=2, third row: xxx, fourth row:`.  Your "first row" is the row with "A" or "B" as your description says "if two columns have the same values in the first row".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, having string and integer mixed in in a single column is not as practical. It is better to have the letter row as part of the column name or pivot this dataframe to have the letter row as a column.

I will show how you can make the letter row as part of column name and get average from there.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    ['2', '4', '3', '2', '1'],
    ['0', '1', '2', '4', '0'],
    ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
], ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])

letter_row = df.filter(df.col1.rlike('[^\d]')).take(1)[0]
new_cols = [f'{letter_row[x]}_{x}' for x in letter_row.asDict()]

df = df.filter(df.col1.rlike('\d+')).toDF(*new_cols)

# df.show()
# +------+------+------+------+------+
# |A_col1|B_col2|B_col3|A_col4|B_col5|
# +------+------+------+------+------+
# |     2|     4|     3|     2|     1|
# |     0|     1|     2|     4|     0|
# |     1|     1|     1|     1|     1|
# +------+------+------+------+------+

acols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('A_')]
bcols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('B_')]

df = (df.withColumn('A_avg', sum(F.col(x) for x in acols) / len(acols))
      .withColumn('B_avg', sum(F.col(x) for x in bcols) / len(bcols)))
```

Result

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
|A_col1|B_col2|B_col3|A_col4|B_col5|A_avg|B_avg|
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
|     2|     4|     3|     2|     1|  2.0| 2.66|
|     0|     1|     2|     4|     0|  2.0|  1.0|
|     1|     1|     1|     1|     1|  1.0|  1.0|
+------+------+------+------+------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: `acols`, `bcols` part is not dynamic. If you want to make it more dynamic, try using loop.  Hopefully, this gets you some ideas to start from.  If the # of columns is small, this is fine but if it is wider and many groups of each letter, consider the pivot approach.